# How do I separate chapters and insert a few empty lines between two chapters?

Tags: chapters, titlesec, etoolbox, report, clearpage

I know it has been asked before but I just can't seem to make it work not matter what I try.

I am using the `report` class. Now I want **only** my chapters to start below the end of the preceeding chapter. By **only** I mean: I also have a title page and a table of content which should stand alone, so this thread of chapters should start with the first actual chapter (`Summary`).

My very basic structure therefore looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\huge\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{15pt}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Summary}
\input{Chapters/Summary.tex}
\chapter{Chap1}
\input{Chapters/Chap1.tex}
\chapter{Chap2}
\input{Chapters/Chap2.tex}

\end{document}
```

I DON'T want the chapter `Chap1` to start on a new page but to start after the final sentence of `Summary` with a bit of space between them. Likewise for `Chap2` and `Chap1`.

I have tried adding versions of

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

% and to achieve seperation between the toc and the beginning of the report I added \clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\chapter{Summary}
\input{Chapters/Summary.tex}
% etc.
```

but it didn't work: the chapter titles are simply printed in the last written line of the previous chapter, so there is no seperation between the chapters at all. It seems as though eliminating `\clearpage` eliminates something that tells `\chapter` that it is not part of the preceeding chapter.

The same problem occurs when using

```
\chapter{Summary}
\input{Chapters/Summary.tex}
{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{Chap1}}
\input{Chapters/Chap1.tex}
```

Again I get the error "Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode." This problem occures no matter how I try to replace `\clearpage` (e.g. within a group, using `\renewcommand`). Might there be something wrong with the titlesec package that it doesn't want me to replace the `\clearpage` command by a few lines? Is there something going on in the background with floating elements? How would you solve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: The general typographic tradition is that a chapter starts on a  new page but sections do not. --- GOM

Comment: There is a given amount of pages I have to use, that's my issue...